# Is there a way to something similar to a database but in the user device?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, database

I want to try my first app using just html, css and javascript, and I want to keep it as simple as possible. So I want to know if there is a way to have something like a user side database to save data that the user modify in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  can use localstorage or create txt or json file  save it on user device  and retieve data from it

Comment: Saving to user device isn't very practical,  from a browser it can't happen without manual intervention . Localstorage is a sensible option though